# C++ libs/Compatible issues/cygwin and AWS

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, cygwin

I write C++ programs but not very familiar with the compilers. I want to build some libs locally in my home computer and use it in (Amazon's) AWS. What should I do to make sure that my libs are compatible with the AWS's system?

```
I checked that the AWS's g++ version is:

    g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.8.1

While my cygwin's g++ version is:
    g++ (GCC) 5.4.0

They seem to be much different.
```

Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you provide more details about what are you trying to achieve? Did you try any deployment and have any problems to help with?

Comment: Sorry that the question was not clear.  What I want to do is to build a lib libA with a newer g++ compiler, and another program App_B will use this libA but an older g++ compiler will build App_B. I wonder whether there will be any issue. Thanks!

Comment: It depends. Check some explanation here: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2013-03/msg00022.html also there is dualABI problem described here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I now know what I want to do: install the same compiler in my local machine.  However, I still get problems there.  I will pose another question.